# Access objects by their identifier

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm fetching relational data from my sql database. This data has an identifier (unique/primary key). Sample:

```
[
   {id:1, value:“test“, cat:2},
   {id:2, value:“test“, cat:3},
   {id:3, value:“test“, cat:4}, ...
]
```

As proposed on many sites, including Stackoverflow, you may use an array's find function to access the elements by their id:

[Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Sample to fetch the value of object with id 3:

```
  SomeVal = myArray.find(x => x.id === 3).value
```

However, I disagree with this approach. I don't see why you would search for an identifier, as you could just simply access the element directly via id, which really is the idea to use an identifier.

You may argue that the array's find function will just do the job as it's superfast, but that's not good enough in my case as performance has highest priority.

As result, I currently "misuse" the index of the array as identifier number to access the elements directly. Sample:

```
 SomeVal = myArray[3].value
```

However, I am looking for a more feasable approach in javascript/typescript to access the elements by id directly.

I do not need to create/update/delete the elements, I solely need to access them once fetched.

I must not use arrays at all if another data structure is better for this.

I am NOT proposing to replace an array’s field search function such as find with the direct index access. And the core of the discussion shall not be which array element is accessed by 3, as this is a simple example. The main idea of the question is if it’s feasible to use the index if an array like it was the identifier, hence to use index which directly correlates with the id field.

Comment: The `id` in your array is *not* the index. I can't see how you can retrieve an entry of `id: 3` without using `.find()` or `.findIndex()` with a predicate. `myArray[3]` returns the *fourth* item in the array (because indeces are zero-based), and it doesn't return the entry of `id: 3` as you expected.

Comment: I am aware of that, that's exactly why I said I misuse the index as identifier.

Comment: Suppose you are at the start of a Society (lane of 50 houses) and each house has a unique number (an identifier) from 1 to 50 and they are randomly distributed. You have a friend living at house #20. Now, just because you know the unique number of the house, will you be able to simply jump to that house? No, you need to go through the lane and find house #20.

Comment: There is NO way to access an array by the id without looping. What you are saying is not possible with that data format. If you want to access the items by id, then alter it to be an object/map/set and use the id as the key.

Comment: Having you looked at hash table data structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I disagree with this approach. I don't see why you would search for an identifier, as you could just simply access the element directly via id, which really is the idea to use an identifier.

You **can't** directly access by ID with the structure you've shown. You need a **different** structure to do that.

> As result, I currently "misuse" the index of the array as identifier number to access the elements directly. Sample:
>
> ```
> SomeVal = myArray[3].value
> ```

That doesn't access the entry with `id: 3`. It accesses `undefined` (with your sample data). Indexes start at 0, not 1. Moreover, unless the underlying system guarantees it, you can't rely on the entries being in `id` order with no gaps, etc.

For access by `id`, convert the array to a Map or an object. Then you can reuse that map or object and benefit from the sublinear lookup time on the map key / object property name.

Map (I'd recommend this):

```js
// Note that I've put them out of order to demonstrate we're really getting by id
const array = [
   {id:2, value:"test", cat:3},
   {id:1, value:"test", cat:2},
   {id:3, value:"test", cat:4},// ...
];

const map = new Map(array.map(entry => [entry.id, entry]));

console.log(map.get(1));
```

Object:

```js
// Note that I've put them out of order to demonstrate we're really getting by id
const array = [
   {id:2, value:"test", cat:3},
   {id:1, value:"test", cat:2},
   {id:3, value:"test", cat:4},// ...
];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(entry => [entry.id, entry]));

console.log(obj[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using map, but why is a map superior to using a prepared array which index value correlates with my id?

Comment: @CoffeeCups - If you have an array you can directly index into, that's just as good as a map. But `id`s are usually not nice contiguous low numbers like that, so I was thinking for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to use `find` in this case is because you have an `array of objects`. So you cannot directly access the id key.

If you want to access the id key directly, then you need to convert your array to an object.

Comment: In a pure object there would be only a single property with the key `id`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two approaches to do that.

1. Using a data structure algorithm such as HashTable to find the element easily and in fast time.
2. Create an object that id is key and its value is the entity object. something like this:

   ```js
   const myArray = [...];
   const cachedMyArray = cacheData(myArray);

   const anItem = cachedMyArray[3]

   // Caching data to find elements fastest
   interface MyArray {
     ...
   }

   function cacheData(array: MyArray[]) {
     const cached = {};
     
     array.forEach((item: MyArray) => {
       cached[item.id] = item;
     });
     
     return cached;
   }
   ```